# Rails has_many belongs_to unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models:

Sale:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :sale_item_ids, :subtotal, :tax_charge, :total

  has_many :sale_items

end
```

SaleItem:

```
class SaleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :discount, :price, :product, :quantity, :sale_id, :sum, :code

  belongs_to :sale
end
```

First i create an empty sale and then i start adding sale_items to that sale.

How can i validate the uniqueness of the sale_item_ids column? i mean, how can i make it so the same sale_item  cannot be created twice with the same sale_id?

i have tried:

```
has_many :sale_items, uniq: true
```

but didnt work, i have also tried:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :sale_item_ids
```

but no success.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to scope it. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of
Try this:

`validates_uniqueness_of :sale_items_ids, :scope => :sale_id`

Comment: It didnt work, it keeps saving duplicate records in the sale. Is it possible to acomplish this with a validation in the SaleItem model?

Comment: Nevermind, i am wrong since the beginning, sale_item_ids will always be different because its a new record in the database, so it will always be unique. So what i have to validate is some other column like the code that its unique. Ill try this.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong since the beginning, sale_item_ids will always be different because its a new record in the database, so it will always be unique.

So what i have done is validate some other column.

```
class SaleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_presence, :on => :create

attr_accessible :code, :discount, :price, :product, :quantity, :sum, :sale_id

  belongs_to :sale


  def check_presence
    # Get the sale where the item sale will be saved
    sale = Sale.find(self.sale_id)

    # Compare the code column
    sale.sale_items.each do |s|
      if s.code == self.code
        errors.add(:base, "Item already in the sale form.")
      end
    end
  end

end
```